# Merging MP3 with MP4 using FFMPEG. Unexpected silent at the end

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I'm using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4` to join a part of an mp3 file to a video while converting to AAC, but the last 3 centiseconds of the audio are silent. Is there a way to fix this?

Log: https://jpst.it/2aIIh - This one had 10 ms of silence at the end.

Comment: How are you detecting 3 centiseconds of silence?

Comment: with the waveform

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: https://jpst.it/2aIIh